# Azure CloudBlobStream serialization (with Json.NET)

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, azure-blob-storage

I have a little problem. My environment is a console app in .NET Core 2.1.

Look at the this code:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Test starts: {DateTime.Now.ToString("o")}");

        string connectionString = "[My connection string]";
        string containerName = "mycontainer";

        CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        CloudBlobClient serviceClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = serviceClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

        container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();

        CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference($"{containerName}/Test.txt");
        CloudBlobStream cloudBlobStream = cloudBlockBlob.OpenWriteAsync().Result;

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cloudBlobStream);

        Console.WriteLine($"Test ends: {DateTime.Now.ToString("o")}");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        string stackTrace = e.StackTrace;

        while(e != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            e = e.InnerException;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(stackTrace);
    }
    Console.Write("Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

When I try to serialize the `CloudBlobStream` object with the command `string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cloudBlobStream);`, I obtain the following Exception:

> Error getting value from 'Length' on 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobWriteStream'.
>   Specified method is not supported.
>     at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ExpressionValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)
>     at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)
>     at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
>     at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
>     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
>     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObjectInternal(Object value, Type type, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
>     at AzureBlobStreamSerializationTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Projects\AzureBlobStreamSerializationTest\AzureBlobStreamSerializationTest\Program.cs:line 28

Any idea on how to solve the problem?

Regards,
Attilio

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are trying to accomplish here. Are you trying to read some JSON from the cloud and maybe deserialize it into an object?  Or are you trying to serialize some object and store the JSON into the cloud?  Or something else?  What you are actually doing is trying to serialize the stream object itself, which won't work. The exception is happening because Json.Net is trying to treat the stream like a POCO and read all the public properties from it.  One of those properties is `Length`, which is not readable on a stream that is opened for writing.

Comment: @BrianRogers The code is only to demonstrate the problem. What I want to achive is a json service that returns a stream for read data from or write data to Azure Blob Storage.

Answer (score 8):

In your code it looks like you are literally trying to serialize a `Stream` object as if it were data.  This will not work.  The exception is happening because the serializer is trying to read all the public properties from the `Stream` object.  One of these properties is `Length`, which is not readable when the stream is opened for writing.

I think you are misunderstanding how to use streams with Json.Net and Azure storage blobs.  The `JsonConvert` class is really just a façade, and unfortunately its `SerializeObject()` method does not have an overload that supports streams.  To work with streams using Json.Net, you need to use a `JsonSerializer` instance along with a `StreamWriter` and `JsonTextWriter` if you're serializing to the stream, or `StreamReader` and `JsonTextReader` if you're deserializing from it.

Here are a couple of extension methods which you might find helpful and instructive:

```
public static class BlobExtensions
{
    public static async Task SerializeObjectToBlobAsync(this CloudBlockBlob blob, object obj)
    {
        using (Stream stream = await blob.OpenWriteAsync())
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (JsonTextWriter jtw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
        {
            JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
            ser.Serialize(jtw, obj);
        }
    }

    public static async Task<T> DeserializeObjectFromBlobAsync<T>(this CloudBlockBlob blob)
    {
        using (Stream stream = await blob.OpenReadAsync())
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (JsonTextReader jtr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
            return ser.Deserialize<T>(jtr);
        }
    }
}
```

Now let's say you have a class `Item` representing some data that you want to serialize to JSON and store into an Azure blob:

```
class Item 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Here's how you can do that using the first extension method:

```
...
var item = new Item { Id = 1, Name = "Widget", Price = 2.5 };
cloudBlockBlob.SerializeObjectToBlobAsync(item).Wait();
```

Conversely, if you want to retrieve the JSON from the blob and deserialize it back into an `Item`, you can use the other extension method:

```
var item = cloudBlockBlob.DeserializeObjectFromBlobAsync<Item>().Result;
```

Note: if you are using these methods from within an `async` method, you should use the `await` syntax instead of using `Wait()` and `.Result`, respectively:

```
await cloudBlockBlob.SerializeObjectToBlobAsync(item);

...

var item = await cloudBlockBlob.DeserializeObjectFromBlobAsync<Item>();
```

Comment: Just curious, have you ever tested these extension methods under load? I have code virtually identical to your `SerializeObjectToBlobAsync` we tested for logging. At a rate of about 25 per second, with blob sizes of about 2kb, performance begins falling to its knees (write times of 30+ seconds) within about a minute. When replacing those lines with `await blob.UploadTextAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj))`, writes kept up with no problem.

Comment: We're not yet able to explain why, but these were very controlled and isolated tests and we replicated the same results over and over. Just a word of caution to anyone who might be planning on using this code in a production environment.

Comment: @ToddMenier No, I have not tested these under load.  I was just trying to help the OP understand how to use the streaming capabilities of Json.NET with Azure.  I'm a little bit surprised that streaming turned out to be slower for you than serializing the object first and then uploading it, but then again your blob sizes are *tiny*.  If you had much larger blob sizes, I bet you would see different results.  But this just underscores the need for performance testing on a per-use-case basis.  Something that is fast in one scenario might not be with different parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The paramter of the [CloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.getblockblobreference?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlobContainer_GetBlockBlobReference_System_String_) should be blob name.

please remove the containerName from your code.

```
 CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("Test.txt"); //remove the container name from original code
```

According to the error execption, it indicates that JsonConvert.SerializeObject **doesn't support** CloudBlobStream  as paramter.

> Any idea on how to solve the problem?

If you want to get text string, you could use the `cloudBlockBlob.DownloadTextAsync()`.
So please change your code to following

```
container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("Test.txt"); //make sure that blob is existing
var json = cloudBlockBlob.DownloadTextAsync().Result;
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting me about the container. Please See the above comment to understand my goal.

Comment: `What I want to achive is a json service that returns a stream for read data from or write data to Azure Blob Storage.` I am still confused why you try to use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cloudBlobStream);` @Brian Rogers has given detail information about why it is not supported. If you want to return stream. You could use   `MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();`
                `cloudBlockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream);` and you could return the stream.